# How to Loop through multiple subdirectories to find files using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to loop through multiple subdirectories to find fastq files.

fastq files are in /path/sample/a/b/c/.fastq

currently I use this:

```
${inputDir}/**/**/**/*.fastq
```

My inputdir will be only: /path/sample, since its three sub folders i use "/**/" three times. But sometimes no of subfolders might change.

Is there any other  efficient way to loop through multiple subdirectories.

My bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash -l

CWD=$(pwd)
dateStamp=$(date +%s)
SeqProj="${inputDir}/**/**/**/*.fastq"

for Dir in $SeqProj
do

done
```

Comment: Once you find these two directories, what do you want to do with them? Right now you are just overwriting those readpair variables then exiting. CWD and datestamp are also unused.

Answer (score 2):

```
find / -iname '*.fastq' -exec /path/to/foo.sh {} \;
```

Then `foo.sh` is a script that does whatever you are calling inside your loop, using $1 to reference the file found that had its name passed to the script.

Mike's answer also works, it just really depends on what you want to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `find`:

```
for Dir in $(find "$inputDir" -name '*.fastq')
```